# Linux Shell Script to find disk usage and email user with file bigger than limit

Tags: linux, shell

I want to implement a script that find disk usage of all users in /home directory and email any user that has a file bigger than the memory limit(that we determine).After this the script must message root administrator and write username(of anyone with a file bigger than limit) into a file.At first I need to search into a .txt file with this format: 
username:email and save username and email in 2 variables.So my script has **to do this**

```
:.. for every_user do
                du -sh /home/$USERNAME #$username read from .txt file
              if [ $USED -gt $LIMIT ] 
                 #email user to mail read from .txt file
```

I have also found the command to isolate username to save it to variable:

```
echo $line |awk -F ":" '{print $1}'
```

Comment: I'm 99% sure this has been asked before. try searching for `[bash] du mailx` (and other mail agents) . Good luck.

Comment: On Linux each user's mail store will be split between his *inbox* residing in `/var/spool/mail/username` and the messages the user stores locally in folders under his mail directory (usually `~/Mail` or `~/mail`). All stored account founders, etc, will reside there. If you have a standard mail directory under `~/`, you can then simply use `du` twice (once on `/var/spool/mail/username` and again for `~/Mail`) to the the total for any user.

Answer (score 1):

Following command will help you to find the large files

```
find / -type f -size +20M -exec ls -lh {} \; | awk '{ print $NF ": " $5 }'
```

in place of +20M you can place your variable $Limit

mail function can be used to send mail